# Convert a file into CSV with newline as the delimiter

Tags: shell, csv, awk

I've got a lot of data that is new line delimited, copied raw from a server.  However, I cannot convert it into a CSV by simply replacing all `\n` into a comma since I need to have the fields.  There are 9 fields in this occasion.  How can I convert this data?
Keeping in mind that the last element doesn't need a comma since that will need to retain the newline character.

I am horrible at regular expression foo, but since I have the loop being needed, I assume I will need to make this into a shell script?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Example data:

```
Name
Logon User
IP Address
Version
Last Login
Restart Required
Foo1
Foo2
Foo3
Jon Weinraub
jweinraub
10.18.66.10
3.1.1.1
2013-08-19 14:33:11
No
Bar1
Bar2
Bar3
Homer Simpson
....
```

So essentially it should be

```
Name,Logon User, IP,...Foo3
Jon Weinraub,jweinraub,10.18.66.10,...Bar3
Homer Simpson,....
```

Comment: Is the data currently "one data element per line"?

Comment: So you want to replace every instance of `\n` with a comma except in every 9th line?

Comment: I added example data above in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly elaborate way to do it (but it's easy to understand and modify) using `awk`:

Create a file `makeCSV.awk` with the following script:

```
BEGIN {
  count = 0; 
}

{
  count++;
  if (count == 9)
  { 
    count = 0;
    printf "%s\n", $0;
  }
  else
  {
    printf "%s, ", $0;
  }
}
```

Then you can execute this from the command line with

```
awk -f makeCSV.awk myInputFile > myOutputFile.csv
```

Comment: two comments: a, the BEGIN block doesn't make sense, could be saved(removed). b, don't use something like `printf $0`. you don't know if the line containing some format string, like `%d,%s..`. always give a format when use `printf`

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I needed.  I keep forgetting I can use awk as a scripting language too since I typically use it to parse columns with print $3, etc.

Comment: In theory, you should use `printf "%s\n", $0` to avoid problems if the line contains any `%` characters.  You probably don't want the space after the comma, either, so that should be `printf "%s,", $0`.  The semicolons are only needed if there's more than one statement on a line, though they do no harm either.

Comment: @Kent - I like to explicitly initialize my variables, even if the interpreter will "do the right thing". It's an old habit. Agree about the point you and Jonathan made - to use an explicit formatting string. @JonathanLeffler: Putting the space there or not is something I will let Jon W decide. And I originally wrote this as one line, then decided to add CR to make it more readable; but didn't delete the `;`. Does the job...

Comment: @Kent. There is no problem removing formatting on on the printf command. Are you saying that this is ok `awk '/pattern/ {print}'` but this is not ok `awk '/pattern/'` Here print is default action and could be removed.  For printf, `"%s"`is the default action and could therefor be removed.

Comment: @Jotne you didn't get what I was talking about.

Comment: Regarding `printf $0` need to have formatting codes, see your comment number 1.  I do see now what you mean, did not think of this.  Eks `echo "123 %s123" | awk '{printf "%s",$0}'` vs `echo "123 %s123" | awk '{printf $0}'`

Answer (score 4):

does this line work for your requirement?

```
awk 'NR%9{printf "%s,",$0;next}7' file
```

for example:

```
kent$  seq 36|awk 'NR%9{printf "%s,",$0;next}7'
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27
28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36
```

Comment: This is a great one-liner too!

Comment: Why do you use `7` to print?  In 99.9% of awk I have seen people uses `1`.  I would suggest you to do the same.  This is to make it easy for novice to understand that tings are the same.

Comment: @Jotne I prefer to use right index finger and I like 7 more than 1. For novice it is better to see different thing. They would know all number except 0 would work.  Thx for your suggestion. But I would stick to 7

Comment: 7 is cute, but this is terribly verbose!

Answer (score 1):

A nice awk variant:

```
awk 'ORS = NR%9 ? "," : "\n"'
```

ORS is the output record separator.  It is set to "," for all lines but the 9th, and since it is always either "," or "\n" the expression always evaluates to true and the default action to print the record (the line followed by ORS) is executed on each line of input.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before as well, and I may be mistaked, but I solved my issue by adding "\r\n" to the end of the line to put the next bit of data onto a new line. So for example you have something like

```
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
```

You'd need to replace the last comma with an "\r\n". Let me know if this isn't what you're asking for...